# Why won't SQL Server register my assembly as SAFE?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

On SQL Server 2008, I'm attempting to register an assembly that seems to only reference the [supported libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx).  Here is the T-SQL code that I'm using to register the assembly:

```
create assembly MySpatial from 'c:\Spatial.dll'
```

This results in the following error:

> Msg 6509, Level 16, State 31, Line 1
>   An error occurred while gathering
>   metadata from assembly 'Spatial' with
>   HRESULT 0x80004005.

However, if I add `with permission_set=unsafe`, then SQL will execute the command successfully.  How can I find out why the error occurred, or why my assembly must be registered as unsafe?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with my assembly. There aren't any non-`readonly` static fields/properties and it's only referencing safe `mscorlib.dll` and `System.dll`, both v2. I tried copying a limited part of the classes into a separate file and compile, which works, so there's something specific that prevents it from being accepted as safe.

Comment: I've found the issue with my assembly, it has some lambda expressions inside a `GetEnumerator()` method, so I converted them to regular methods + `new Func<>` (converting them to anonymous methods didn't help). This allowed me to add the assembly to SQL Server without getting the error. I still don't know exactly why those lambda expressions caused this (they could compile and run fine outside SQL Server).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same thing, and after some investigation, I think it's because of optimization that the compiler does on lambda expressions.  There's some overhead in creation a delegate from a lambda expression.  I think it must lazy initialize a hidden static field containing the delegate the first time the lambda is accessed so it can reuse the already constructed delegate in future calls.

The reason I think this is because if the lambda captures any variables, it doesn't cause the SAFE issue.  It would make sense that if it's capturing variables, you would need to create a different delegate for each time it's called, but if the lambda is completely self contained, it could cache it for efficiency purposes.

Microsoft did fix the issue in SQL 2008, but they won't fix it in SQL 2005, so if there's a need to support existing SQL 2005 installations, all it requires is eliminating "statically optimizable" lambdas, not all the lambdas in the whole assembly.

Answer (score 1):

When persmission set is unsafe, SQL won't verify the metadata of your assembly.

Try to apply the hotfix from [KB 941256](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941256), or apply [CU4 for SP2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941450). Altough is a different HRESULT than the `E_FAIL` you're getting, perhaps the hotfix addresses the issue.

Comment: Sure, I understand that when permissions are set to unsafe that SQL will just let it through.  However, I'm trying to find out what is it about my assembly that isn't considered safe?

Also, the links that you provided only apply to SQL Server 2005, not 2008.