# error SQL70015: Keyword or statement option 'UNSAFE' is not supported for the targeted platform

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Visual Studio 2015

When I try to build and publish MS SQL database to azure v12

truthworthy property set to ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a ton of detail to go off of; it appears that you might have been writing C# (which would explain your VS usage) and wanted to use pointers- which you shouldn't generally do in a managed language like C#.

Aside from that: Since your error references SQL, it appears as if you may have tried to load it into a SQL DB as an assembly: Your deployment to Azure (SQL DB?) V12 would have been blocked because CLR assemblies are not allowed in the SQL DB service.

For reference on that: [See the link Martyn C posted](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/)  under 'Features not supported in SQL Database', you'll see '.NET Framework CLR integration with SQL Server', which is what I suspect you tried.

Related (but not directly part of the answer) is CLR assemblies being safe/unsafe, [here's a quite comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796596/6146027).

Answer (score 0):

Not really a lot of detail to add here but make sure the operation you are performing is [supported](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/) in SQL Azure.

As it's a PaaS offering then a few things are not supported like they would be in a full deployment of SQL Server.